# Connect to powershell through SSH with keyexchange?

Tags: windows, powershell

I have little experience with Windows systems. Coming from a Linux background I was wondering if there is a way that I can ssh to powershell from a Linux shell?

If this is not possible, is there a key exchange like way to connect from powershell to powershell? I prefer it if I do not need to enter a password for every single server every time.

If this all sounds a bit crazy and there are better ways that windows does this, then feel free to share.

Comment: Powershell has its own remoting technology built in to version 2.  Have you looked at it?

Comment: I know it has a remoting technology in it, but I  don't know if it has something like key exchange.

Comment: I believe it uses your Windows credentials unless you tell it otherwise.  Which would make it invisible to you (no password) much like key exchange. Perhaps you should experiment first.

Comment: if going between ps to ps then look up get-credentials. The results of this can be securely stored and reused.

Comment: http://bsonposh.com/archives/338 shows a good example of how to do this ps to ps with a key exchange like process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So far this is best way for me:

http://www.powershellinside.com/powershell/ssh/download.aspx

You can try it first.

Comment: The name of the company behind it /n can be easily mistaken for a typo. :)

Answer (score 1):

Install SSH server on windows, then run powershell :)

example:

Cygwin - http://www.cygwin.com/

Cygwin SSHD howto - http://www.noah.org/ssh/cygwin-sshd.html

Comment: Can you install ssh as a service through the $ADMIN share on a remote machine as `psexec` installs `psexesvc`?

Comment: I think cygwin installer doesn't support non-GUI install, even non-interactive. But I think there will be other way to run non-popular ssh daemon or opensource SSHD: https://www.google.ge/search?num=100&hl=ka&q=sshd+windows+free&oq=sshd+windows+free&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_l=serp.3...1099.1671.0.1748.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0...0.0.Em2ZUZERUkQ